# Debug a shared C++ library with CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have a question related to debugging a shared library with codeblocks in Ubuntu. I have no problem when I run the program with the shared library. The main problem, however, is that when I debug the program, I cannot go into the source codes of the shared library. The source codes of the shared library is provided, and I build the shared library first before I build the program. I guess that I need to set some parameters for the program's codeblocks project before running the debugging, but I have no idea where I should do the setting. Many thanks.

EDIT:

My project structure is something like that:

`./program`    the running application program that will invoke `run_test.so`

`run_test.so`   the test dynamic library that will invoke `basic_library.so`

`basic_library.so`  the library called by `run_test.so`

When I debug `./program` project I can go into the source codes of  `run_test.so` , but when I want to step into the functions coming from `basic_library.so` in the source code of `run_test.so`, I have problems. It just ignore the step into command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a careful examination, I found the reason why I cannot debug the shared library, in CMAKE scrip I have the following code:

```
set_target_properties(basic_library PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-W1 --strip-all".
```

After I remove --strip-all, I can debug now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the shared library with debug symbols. There are instructions [here](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Debugging_with_Code%3a%3aBlocks)

Essentially, `Project build options | Produce debugging symbols`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my codeblocks (12.11 in Ubuntu) there is no option seting for Produce debugging symbols.

Comment: @feelfree what compiler (and version) are you using with code::blocks and what version of code::blocks itself do you have?

Comment: @PeterT I am using GCC compiler, and the version is 4.6. Codeblocks' version is 12.11 in Ubuntu.

Comment: @feelfree you can go to the "other options" tab and write `-g` on an empty line. But I'm pretty sure that the option should be there.

Comment: @PeterT Thanks for the suggestion. But I cannot find "other options" in Project build options. Where can I find the "other options" tab?

Comment: @feelfree it's really not hard to find it, [here it is](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1589003/in_forums/stackoverflow/codeblocks.jpg).

Comment: @PeterT I have found it, and have done as you suggested. However, I still cannot debug the shared library.

Comment: @PeterT Thanks, and I have seen your illustration. But the "other options" I have found is different from yours. I found it in Global compiler settings https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92688392/Global_compiler_settings.png

Comment: @PeterT I am sure that during the compilation I have used -g options for gcc.

Comment: @PeterT I have found the reason why I have the problem. Thanks for your comments.